# Remember selected TabLayout tab in Kotlin fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-savedstate

What's the correct way to remember the selected tab from a `TabLayout` in a `Fragment` whenever its parent `Activity` has restarted? My `savedInstanceState` if statement doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            my_tabs.getTabAt(savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_FRAGMENT))
        }

        val adapter = MyViewPagerAdapter((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.item_a), FragmentA())
        adapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.item_b), FragmentB())
        adapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.item_c), FragmentC())
        adapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.item_d), FragmentD())

        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        my_tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` from within `onCreateView`? Probably unrelated to your problem but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0 #3

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So are you saying it should be declared in `onViewCreated`?

Comment: No, I'm saying a ViewPager's FragmentPagerAdapter needs to look like this: https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/c643f03a023a9cbe83fff6c75c948d3b or you will have problems.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Ok but this still means that I’d have to create a FragmentPagerAdapter for every ViewPager as each one has a different number of tabs.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that link also contains deprecated code

Comment: Of course it does, they deprecated FragmentPagerAdapter like a week ago, because they want you to use FragmentStatePager and ViewPager2. Doesn't mean it doesn't work. And yes, at least that way your PagerAdapter wouldn't crash in production ;) but you can also pass in `() -> Fragment` dynamically, that would work better than what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your current tab position in shared preference and on activity restarted set that tab position from shared preference